# creating complex url

Tags: ruby, dreamhost

I'm trying to access Dreamhost API to send a mail.

The API expects an url containing domains and the actual emailcontent

> ```
> domain = 'https://api.dreamhost.com/'
> key = "dq86ds5qd4sq"
> command = "announcement_list-post_announcement"
> mailing = "mailing"
> domain = "domain.nl"
> listname = "mailing Adventure"<mailling@domain.nl>"
> message = '<html>html here</html>'
>
> url = domain + "&key=#{key}&cmd=#{command}&listname=#{mailing}&domain=#{domain}&listname=#{listname}&message=#{message}"
>
> uri = URI.parse(url)
> http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
> http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == "https"  # enable SSL/TLS
> http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
>
> http.start {
>  # http.request_get(uri.path) {|res|
>  #   print res.body
>  # }
> }
> ```

When I parse the url I get an error

> bad URI(is not URI?)

The url contains url itself from the listname and message and I assume this causes the problem. I have no clue on how to approack this. CGI escpae has been suggested but that seems to convert white space into +.

Someone knows how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this line

```
url = domain + "&key=#{key}&cmd=#{command}&listname=#{mailing}&domain=#{domain}&listname=#{listname}&message=#{message}"
```

the url is coming out as:

```
"domain.nl&key=dq86ds5qd4sq&cmd=announcement_list-post_announcement&listname=mailing&domain=domain.nl&listname=mailing Adventure<mailling@domain.nl>&message=<html>html here</html>"
```

which is not a proper url. That's why the exception is generated.

One quick fix is as follows:

```
url = "http://" + domain + "/?key=#{key}&cmd=#{command}&listname=#{mailing}&domain=#{domain}&listname=#{URI.escape(listname)}&message=#{URI.escape(message)}"

uri = URI.parse(url)
```

**URI.escape** is used to escape unformatted strings.

Hope this helps.